# not getting target terminal on beagle board

Tags: linux, embedded, beagleboard

I have beagle board. I am able to mount kernel and root file system on the board. But I am not getting the terminal .Root file system is successfully mounted.but its not giving the target prompt(#). so can anyone suggest the solution

Comment: after loading the kernel and root file system i am getting the message"mounted filesystem with write back data mode". and my target terminal stops here. no target prompt is coming..i have DM3530 TI processor on beagle board.

Comment: Hi, you should check the /etc/inittab file on the root filesystem. This file should spawn a login process on your serial port. Have a look at this http://linux.about.com/od/ttl_howto/a/hwtttl15t01.htm and make sure your serial port device is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

BeagleBoard by default doesn't enable serial login.  As dien mentioned, you need to edit /etc/inittab.  But here's a post specifically explaining this for beagle board (see section "Serial Console"). http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Hitchhikers_Guide_to_the_PandaBoard